# .htaccess redirect behaviour

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a .htaccess file which redirects the user to https:// and adds /de/index if nothing else is specified.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(hotelaccess)($|/) - [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}   !^443$
RewriteRule  (.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/de/index  [L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mypage\.de
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mypage.de/de/index [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

but now if I enter https://www.mypage.de it get's redirected to https://www.mypage.de/index ? Why is that and what do I have to add to fix this?
Clarification: The default URL should always be https://www.mypage.de/de/index if entering with and without www and both http:// and https:// (also with or without www)

Comment: well, almost: `de/bar -> de/index` `en/index -> en/index` `/hotelaccess --> ignore all rules except for http(s):// & (www)`So basically: Not de or en --> de // not index --> index // /hotelaccess --> /hotelaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your redirects first, then your rewrites. You can also combine the two redirects into a single rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^mypage\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mypage.de/$1 [R,L] 

# for no URI
RewriteRule ^$ /de/index [L]

# for hotelaccess
RewriteRule ^hotelaccess - [L]

# for everything else
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: almost perfect, only `/de/foo` or `/en/foo/` won't get redirected?